# Trim ArrayList to a set number based on position

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have an arraylist that gets all media items from recyclerview. I then find the position of the selected media. I am sending that arraylist to another activity via ParcelableArrayList. Problem is if the size is over 1,000 i am getting a transaction too large exception on some devices.

What I want to do is this. If arraylist size is over 1000, find the center (pos) and keep 25 on each side of that position within the array.

Example 1. current size is 2,000 and pos is 100. I would like to trim that arraylist (or create new arraylist) that is pos 75 - 125 and discard the rest.

Example 2. if current size is 2,000 and pos is 0, i would like to keep 0-25.

```
ArrayList<Media> current = new ArrayList<>(mAdapter.getMedia());
    for (int i = 0; i < current.size(); i++) {
        if (current.get(i).getPath().equalsIgnoreCase(media.getPath()))
            pos = i;
    } 

if (current.size() > 1000){

}
```

Comment: Check out [`List#subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
if (current.size() > 1000){
    int from = Math.max(0, pos - 25);
    int to = Math.min(pos + 25, current.size()); // or perhaps pos + 26?
    current = new ArrayList<>(current.subList(from, to));
}
```

If your other code allows it, it would be better to change the declared type of `current` from `ArrayList<Media>` to `List<Media>`. Then you could replace the last line of the `if` block with:

```
current = current.subList(from, to);
```

That would avoid the copying involved in constructing a new `ArrayList`.

Of course, if you need the original `current` for other processing, just store the sublist in a different variable.

Comment: That looks exactly like what i want. however I get an incompatible type on current = current.sublist(from, to); Has to be arraylist to send to activity

Comment: @Bignadad - Sorry about that. I updated my answer to deal with the type mismatch.